# How to Create Mandatory Dependency Property in XAML WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am creating User Control. I created three dependency properties which the user should bind to a viewmodel in XAML.

Is there something I can do so if developer does not bind the property? Ideally, the project would not compile successfully.

Comment: Throw exception, for example, why not?

Comment: Set a default values for your dependency properties. There nothing you can do to fail the build, if there is no errors.

Comment: I absolutely agree with this question. It would be nice to get the same sort of compile-time behavior in xaml as you can get in code.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Bindings are only checked at run-time, not at compile-time. The reason for this is that the compiler cannot determine what datacontext you wish to set for a view while the application is running since you can always change the datacontext.

If you're interested you can look up the MVVM design pattern to learn more about the reason why the model and view are seperated.

Comment: Bindings are only checked at run-time but that's not the question. The question was about not having a binding at all, not whether it doesn't evaluate to something.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer The question explicitly ask to check at compile time if a binding is used. Since a binding is only checked at run-time this is imposible. At least I cannot find any other interpretation of "Is there something I can do so if developer does not bind the property? Ideally, the project would not compile successfully."